# Kivy DragBehavior. Dragging more than one widget

Tags: kivy

I'm looking for a way to mark some `widgets` and drag them. What I've managed to do on my own is to `draw` a `rectangle` and find if the `widget` is within its borders. Now I think I should somehow cheat other `widgets` so they think `touch_down` was in their `collide point`. I've tried but it doesn't work.

**CODE**

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1280')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
import copy
kv = """

<FileBox>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 100
    bcolor: (.5,.5,.5,1)
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)  if self.bcolor is None else self.bcolor
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size    

<FileSpace>
    orientation: 'lr-tb'
    spacing: 2


FileSpace:
    FileBox:
    FileBox:

"""

class FileBox(DragBehavior, BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(FileBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class FileSpace(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(FileSpace, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.touch_count = 0
        self.files = set()

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        # remove rectangle if exists
        try:
            touch.ud['rectangle'].size = (0,0)
        except Exception:
            pass
        self.touch_count = 0

        # try to cheat other widgets with touch posistion in their collide point
        for file in self.files:
            touch.pos = file.pos
            file.on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self.touch_count == 0:
            print('TOUCH DOWN', touch)
            # copy of the point of rectangle
            self.touch_down_pos = copy.deepcopy(touch)
            self.touch_count += 1

            with self.canvas:
                touch.ud['rectangle'] = Rectangle(pos=(touch.x, touch.y), size = (0,0))
        # draw a rectangle
        touch.ud['rectangle'].size = (touch.x - self.touch_down_pos.x, touch.y - self.touch_down_pos.y)
        for child in self.children:
            # center of a widget
            center = [child.pos[0] + child.width/2, child.pos[1] + child.height/2]

            x = False
            y = False
            if (touch.x > center[0] and self.touch_down_pos.x < center[0]) or (touch.x < center[0] and self.touch_down_pos.x > center[0]):
                x = True
            if (touch.y > center[1] and self.touch_down_pos.y < center[1]) or (touch.y < center[1] and self.touch_down_pos.y > center[1]):
                y = True
            if x and y:
                child.bcolor = (255/255, 153/255, 51/255, 1)
                self.files.add(child)
            else:
                child.bcolor = (.5,.5,.5,1)
                try:
                    self.files.remove(child)
                except Exception:
                    pass

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class SFTP(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'SFTP'

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SFTP().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to trick the `File` `Widgets`, just move them yourself. Here is a version of your code that does what I think you want:

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1280')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
import copy
kv = """

<FileBox>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 100
    bcolor: (.5,.5,.5,1)
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)  if self.bcolor is None else self.bcolor
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size    

<FileSpace>
    orientation: 'lr-tb'
    spacing: 2


FileSpace:
    FileBox:
    FileBox:

"""

class FileBox(DragBehavior, BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(FileBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class FileSpace(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(FileSpace, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.touch_count = 0
        self.files = set()
        self.move_files = False

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        # remove rectangle if exists
        try:
            touch.ud['rectangle'].size = (0,0)
        except Exception:
            pass
        self.touch_count = 0
        if self.move_files:
            self.move_files = False
            for file in self.files:
                file.bcolor = (.5,.5,.5,1)
            self.files = set()
        return super(FileSpace, self).on_touch_up(touch)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if len(self.files) > 0:
            self.move_files = True
        return super(FileSpace, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self.move_files:
            for file in self.files:
                if not file.collide_point(*touch.pos):  # avoid double move if touch is on one of the chosen files
                    file.pos = (file.x + touch.dx, file.y + touch.dy)
        else:
            if self.touch_count == 0:
                print('TOUCH Move on', self, touch)
                # copy of the point of rectangle
                self.touch_down_pos = copy.deepcopy(touch)
                self.touch_count += 1

                with self.canvas:
                    touch.ud['rectangle'] = Rectangle(pos=(touch.x, touch.y), size = (0,0))
            # draw a rectangle
            touch.ud['rectangle'].size = (touch.x - self.touch_down_pos.x, touch.y - self.touch_down_pos.y)
            for child in self.children:
                # center of a widget
                center = [child.pos[0] + child.width/2, child.pos[1] + child.height/2]

                x = False
                y = False
                if (touch.x > center[0] and self.touch_down_pos.x < center[0]) or (touch.x < center[0] and self.touch_down_pos.x > center[0]):
                    x = True
                if (touch.y > center[1] and self.touch_down_pos.y < center[1]) or (touch.y < center[1] and self.touch_down_pos.y > center[1]):
                    y = True
                if x and y:
                    child.bcolor = (255/255, 153/255, 51/255, 1)
                    self.files.add(child)
                else:
                    child.bcolor = (.5,.5,.5,1)
                    try:
                        self.files.remove(child)
                    except Exception:
                        pass
        return super(FileSpace, self).on_touch_move(touch)

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class SFTP(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'SFTP'

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SFTP().run()
```

So, I have added a `self.move_files` variable that acts as a mode flag indicating that the selected `Widgets` are being moved, if it `True`. Also added `on_touch_down()` that sets `self.move_files` to `True` if there is a touch event after files have been selected.

The `on_touch_move()` method moves the selected `Widgets` if `self.move_files` is True. The `collide_point()` check is to avoid applying the move to a `Widget` twice (when the user actually drags one of the selected `Widgets`).

The `on_touch_up()` method now clears the selected `Widgets` and resets `self.move_files` to `False`.

I also added `super` calls to all the `on_touch` methods.

Comment: That's perfect! Exacly what I expected.